# How can overflow be visible vertically and not horizontally?

Tags: html, css, overflow

```js
let hoverBtn1 = document.getElementById("hoverButton1");
let hoverList1 = document.getElementById("hoverList1");

const showList = () => {
    hoverList1.style.display = "flex";
};
const hideList = () => {
    hoverList1.style.display = "none";
};

hoverBtn1.addEventListener("mouseover", showList);
hoverBtn1.addEventListener("mouseout", hideList);

// function columns() {
//   for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
//     let hoverBtn = hoverBtn + i
//     let hoverBtn += document.getElementById("hoverButton" + i);
//     let hoverList = document.getElementById("hoverList" + i);

//     const showList = () => {
//       hoverList.style.display = "flex";
//     }
//     const hideList = () => {
//       "hoverList" + i.style.display = "none";
//     }

//     "hoverBtn" + i.addEventListener('mouseover', showList);
//     "hoverBtn" + i.addEventListener('mouseout', hideList);
//   }
// }
// columns();
```

```css
.main-container {
    width: 220px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    border: gray solid 2px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.column {
    width: 100px;
    border: blue solid 1px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.hoverButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.hoverList {
    border: gray solid 2px;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container" class="main-container">
    <div id="column1" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton1" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList1" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="column2" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton2" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList2" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="column3" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton3" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList3" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="column4" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton4" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList4" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have these dropdown menus on the bottom that I need to be able to show but they get cut off by CSS overflow on the main container. Unfortunately, I'm told I can't add more white-space to the bottom and so I'm stuck with this container width/height because it messes up page spacing on my real website. Pretend the columns that go horizontally are part of a carousel. Unfortunately they  get revealed when the main containers overflow hidden property is deleted. So I  guess I have to supposedly keep this overflow hidden for horizontal, but need a solution to get these dropdowns to show vertically when you hover on this button.

I tried playing with z-index/position but it doesn't get the dropdown menu to show. I tried adding 100px of padding and -100px of margin to bottom of main container (not that 100 is the important amount, just trying to keep the white-spacing the same), but that messed with page layout elsewhere, so I don't think it's an option either.

Comment: https://codepen.io/etherealcodingpro/pen/BavBVom

Comment: oh and I can't have scrollbars because thats also considered bad UI

Comment: What you're trying to do is still confusing to me.

Comment: I see a hover button in your codepen example. Where do you want the popup box to display after you hover over the button?

Comment: I want the popup to display right under the hover button, but I don't want it to be cut off by the main container box with  its css overflow: hidden property. Only the colums should be hidden by overflow.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the vertical overflow to be visible, use `overflow-x: clip` instead of `overflow-x: hidden`

[MDN References > `overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)

> If `overflow-x` is `hidden`, `scroll`, or `auto` and the `overflow-y` property is `visible` (default), the value will be implicitly computed as `auto`.
>
> `auto`
> Overflow content is clipped at the element's padding box, and overflow content can be scrolled into view.

```js
let hoverBtn1 = document.getElementById("hoverButton1");
let hoverList1 = document.getElementById("hoverList1");

const showList = () => {
    hoverList1.style.display = "flex";
};
const hideList = () => {
    hoverList1.style.display = "none";
};

hoverBtn1.addEventListener("mouseover", showList);
hoverBtn1.addEventListener("mouseout", hideList);

// function columns() {
//   for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
//     let hoverBtn = hoverBtn + i
//     let hoverBtn += document.getElementById("hoverButton" + i);
//     let hoverList = document.getElementById("hoverList" + i);

//     const showList = () => {
//       hoverList.style.display = "flex";
//     }
//     const hideList = () => {
//       "hoverList" + i.style.display = "none";
//     }

//     "hoverBtn" + i.addEventListener('mouseover', showList);
//     "hoverBtn" + i.addEventListener('mouseout', hideList);
//   }
// }
// columns();
```

```css
.main-container {
    width: 220px;
    overflow-x: clip;
    height: 300px;
    border: gray solid 2px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.column {
    width: 100px;
    border: blue solid 1px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.hoverButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.hoverList {
    border: gray solid 2px;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container" class="main-container">
    <div id="column1" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton1" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList1" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="column2" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton2" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList2" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="column3" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton3" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList3" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="column4" class="column">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <br />
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <div>paragraph</div>
        <br />
        <button id="hoverButton4" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
        <div id="hoverList4" class="hoverList" style="display: none">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Additionally, you can replace the JavaScript with simple CSS

```
.hoverButton:hover + .hoverList {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.main-container {
  width: 220px;
  overflow-x: clip;
  height: 300px;
  border: gray solid 2px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.column {
  width: 100px;
  border: blue solid 1px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.hoverButton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.hoverButton:hover + .hoverList {
  display: block;
}

.hoverList {
  border: gray solid 2px;
  height: fit-content;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container" class="main-container">
  <div id="column1" class="column">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <br />
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <br />
    <button id="hoverButton1" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
    <div id="hoverList1" class="hoverList">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="column2" class="column">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <br />
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <br />
    <button id="hoverButton2" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
    <div id="hoverList2" class="hoverList">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="column3" class="column">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <br />
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <br />
    <button id="hoverButton3" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
    <div id="hoverList3" class="hoverList">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="column4" class="column">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <br />
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <div>paragraph</div>
    <br />
    <button id="hoverButton4" class="hoverButton">hover to show </button>
    <div id="hoverList4" class="hoverList">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: overflow-x: clip worked!!! thank you. I was really stuck on this. I read the description of it on mdn and thought it wouldn't work. You are a live saver, sir

Answer (score 0):

Well, haven't you tried instead of putting a `height` in your `.main-container` try a `min-height` i think this will fix your problem

Comment: yeah, this was already mentioned in the description. Can't adjust the height.

Comment: sorry about that, wish i could :\

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow y scroll

```css
.main-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: sorry this was already  said in a comment, but i cant have scroll bars be used, i need the hover button to display the entire list without a scroll bar needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y: auto` to the main-container

```
.main-container {
  /* other stuff here */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: already said this in a couple comments, but can't have scrolling. i need the popup to just be visually present.

Comment: sorry about that :\

Comment: I have used overflow-y: auto without generating a scroll bar, though.